# Not getting paging links when using WP_Query in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not getting paging links when using WP_Query in WordPress. I am trying to fetch all the products on the page and show them in page by page manner. For this I want to show the paging links on the bottom. But paging links are not showing.

Below is the link - [here](http://www.fortuneshop9999.com/%E9%9B%9E%E5%B9%B4%E5%B0%8F%E8%B2%BC%E5%A3%AB-3/)

And the code for this is:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged'          => $paged
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile;
?>
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>

<? wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**next_posts_link();** and **previous_posts_link();** and not showing links.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead of of above code.

```
<?php
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query= null;

   $postsPerPage = 3;
    $argsev = array(
      'post_type'     =>  'product',
      'post_status'   =>  'publish',
      'posts_per_page'  =>  $postsPerPage,
      'paged' => $paged
    );  

     $wp_query = new WP_Query($argsev);
      while (  $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        global $product;
        echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
      endwhile; ?>

    <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
  <?php
  $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
  wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: thank you it works great. Just one more question how to add numbered paging like 'previous, 1, 2...10, next' ?

Comment: You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ for making numbers pagination. You will have to call wp_pagenavi(); in the place of next_post_link(); & previous_posts_link();